# How to extract all duplicate values from a list?

Tags: python

I have the following list: `friends = ["Brian","John","Brian", "Alena", "Brian"]`. If I use `duplicated()` I only get **Brian** one time, but the result should be `Brian, Brian, Brian` (because the list contains that name three times).

Comment: Does order matter? E.g. should `["A", "B", "A", "B", "C"]` output `["A", "B", "A", "B"]` or `["A", "A", "B", "B"]` (or something else)?

Comment: The output should be ["A", "A", "B", "B"]. So, the order does matter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dups = [f for f in friends if friends.count(f) > 1]
```

Comment: Good! If i have a column within an csv file that contains all the values from above, how can i get the same result ?   data["Friends"] = [f for f in data["Friends"] if data["Friends"].count(f) > 1]   # i've tried like this and it doesn't worked.

Comment: The error is KeyError: 'Level (output omitted)  must be same as name (None)'

Answer (score 0):

```
 # you can try this     
  from collections import Counter
  count =  [count for item, count in Counter(friends).items() if count > 1] # this will 
   give you the count of the duplicated item
  item   =  [item for item, count in Counter(friends).items() if count > 1] # this will 
  return the item itself
```